# How to put my async task data in a spinner?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I'm working on an Android app with some API i made on my own. I'm almost done but i can't find the way to put the data i get inside my async task (the one who's getting my json data) inside my dynamic spinner.

Here is my code :

```
String example;

static final String API_URL2 = "https://xxxxxxxx.xx";
//Start Used for spinner with different value and display
String[] textfordropdown = { "A",
        "B",
        "C",
};
String[] valueofdropdowtext =
        { "1",
                "2",
                "3",
        };
Spinner  spinnerdynamic;
```

OnCreate i've called my async task to see if i get something displayed so yeah it works :

```
new GetList().execute();
```

and i also create my spinner here

```
spinnerdynamic = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
      new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, textfordropdown);
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerdynamic.setAdapter(adapter1);
spinnerdynamic.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);
```

Here is the function onItemSelectedListener1:

```
OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 =
        new OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                example = String.valueOf(valueofdropdowtext[position]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

        };
```

And here my async task :

```
 class GetList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {


    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(API_URL2);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if (response == null) {
            response = "Une erreur c'est produite";
        }

        Log.i("INFO", response);

        try {
            JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
            JSONArray prestationlist = object.getJSONArray("WhatIWant");

            //Permet de compter le nombre d'éléments dans le json array
            int arrSize = prestationlist.length();

            ArrayList<String> value = new ArrayList<String>(arrSize);
            ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>(arrSize);

            for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++) {
                object = prestationlist.getJSONObject(i);
                value.add(object.getString("Value"));
                name.add(object.getString("Text"));
                //Here i've made some display to see if it works, i get the data.
                responseView.setText(value.toString());
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So how can i put my data inside the String[] textfordropdown or valueofdropdowntext ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370107/update-city-spinner-with-notifydatasetchanged-after-state-is-selected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a string array list and initialize it at the top of file

And use that arraylist in your spinner

```
adapter1 =
  new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
         android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourarraylist);
```

And add your values into that array list in your onPostExecute method

```
for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++) {
            object = prestationlist.getJSONObject(i);
            value.add(object.getString("Value"));
            name.add(object.getString("Text"));
            //Here i've made some display to see if it works, i get the data.
           yourarraylist.add(object.getString("Text"));
            responseView.setText(value.toString());
        }
       adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Note: You need to initialize spinner adapter also at the top of the file

Comment: Sounds a good idea but when i put add on my arraylist it gives me an error :  cannot resolve method add(java.lang.string)

Comment: How can i put my value by doing the same ? I want to replace my valueofdropdowntext[position] by my new array

Comment: you need to maintain another string arraylist with same index

Comment: What do you mean ? Because in my spinner i can select my value but when i click on it it seems like nothing's selected, i need my textfordropdown replaced by array text so that's ok but i also need my valueofdropdowntext replace by array value, this is not working :/

Comment: yourspinner.getSelectedItemPosition() using this you will get the index of selected item of the spinner. And you can select the value for  same position in value arraylist..if you are maintaining a valuearraylist also..

Comment: Hmm.. i'm missunderstanding, i've made two array textfordropdown and valueofdropdown, in my async i add(object.getString("Text") in the textfordropdown and i add(object.getString("Value") in the valueofdropdown. Now i can see my text by puting textfordropdown array in adapter1, but i'm getting value position inside onItemSelectedListener1, now how can i get the value from the array since i was using a String[] with int position

Comment: String selectedvalue = yourvaluearraylist.get(yourspinner.getSelectedItemPosition());

Comment: Still getting a null value :/

Comment: check whether your arraylist is having value.... by giving fixed index like  yourvaluearraylist.get(1)... Probably value is not adding  to arraylist properly ..otherwise it should work

Comment: I've made some change on my initial post, part EDITED CODE, that's what i made maybe it's not what you mean ? When i make the get(1) i get my value

Comment: Its perfect... What is the value you are getting on spinner.getSelectedItemPosition Can you do a debug...

Comment: I'm getting a null value :/

Comment: Its strange because i don't see any value before i click on the spinner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146609/discussion-between-christian-pliso-and-ramees).